# Why URLs from NSUserDefaults and CoreData don't allow to send POST request?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xcode7

I need help, 'cause I've run into following problem and don't know about any reasons of it.

If I declare my POST request like this:

```
    let urlString = url.valueForKey("url") as? String
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: urlString!);

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    let postString = "imei=AA022F8E-9E20-482D-80CB-DE06A8CD0990&pin=1234";
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
```

or like this:

```
    requestURL = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(savedPeople) as! String
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: requestURL!);

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"      

    let postString = "imei=AA022F8E-9E20-482D-80CB-DE06A8CD0990&pin=1234";
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
```

it will looks like I sending empty POST request.

But if I do it in common way, like this:

```
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.wtek.ru/test.php");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
    let postString = "imei=AA022F8E-9E20-482D-80CB-DE06A8CD0990&pin=1234";
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
```

it will work correctly.

Also, first two version work correctly when I send request to http://127.0.0.1/request.php, but it doesn't work when I try to send my request outside of local network.

Where can be the problem?

Comment: Http or https? Ios9? Transport security? Firewall?

Comment: Which part of this is a Core Data problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in Core Data / NSUserDefaults.

It happened because I've put to Core Data link without `www`.
So, if you faced with same problem, please, double-check it.